# (413) Request Entity Too Large in IIS 10 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have an IIS 10 server configured as a basic URL Rewrite reverse proxy to preauthenticate requests directed at another web server, the calls are all presenting client certificates over SSL. I'm having issues with (413) Request Entity Too Large errors with large POSTs.

I've tried setting this in applicationHost.config

```
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
```

However this had no effect. Are there any other settings that control URL Rewrite's rejection of large POSTs?

The web.config for the reverse proxy is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://my.internal.server:444/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try changing `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4194304" />`, I think I had that problem before, can't really remember the solution

Comment: Thanks, but that's also already set to 2147483647

Comment: What about `<requestLimits maxQueryString="4294967295" />`

Comment: Aha! You just pointed me in the right direction. It was actually ````<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />```` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: @Michael or TimLett, consider making that an answer. It's not obvious that this question has an answer otherwise, I missed it the first time.

Answer (score 3):

To sum up from the comment.

Try changing `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4194304" />` first.
If it doesn't work try  `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />` next.
If it stills doesn't work leave me a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Normal setting for max upload file size:

Setting the request limits in the root web.config of the site (default is 30 MB). This can be set in Internet Information Services Manager Program also (MACHINE->Site->IIS->Request Filtering->Edit Feature Settings)

```
<!– 100 MB . Format uses Bytes –>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=”102400000″ />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
```